# Resolving Izpack artifacts using maven dependency

Tags: maven-plugin, izpack

I have Izpack installer which packs a pre-configured server and installs in target directory. This server is around 500Mb. Currently I have checked in this src/main/resources folder of installer maven project.But having this big server in git is making the git pulls very slow. So i am planning to keep this server as maven artifact in nexus and add its dependency to installer maven project. This way i can create a maven profile to pull this server from nexus on demand. I am yet to figure out how to copy this dependency to staging folder using a maven plugin(any help would be greatly appreciated).   My question here, is it a right approach? or is there any better way to do this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [maven dependency plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/) to copy a dependeny to a specific folder.

You can use it to either copy all dependencies or even unpack those dependencies.

```
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.10</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>unpack</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>unpack</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <outputDirectory>${izpack.staging}/content/ninjolibs</outputDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Comment: Thanks @oers. It helped

Answer (score 1):

This is what i did. I uploaded wso2.zip  to nexus as zip artifact and configured pom.xml of my installer module to use this dependency.

```
  <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.10</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>copy-binaries</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>copy</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <artifactItems>
                <artifactItem>
                  <groupId>org.wso2</groupId>
                  <artifactId>wso2is</artifactId>
                  <version>5.0.0</version>
                  <type>zip</type>
                  <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                  <outputDirectory>src/main/resources/wso2/binary</outputDirectory>
                  <destFileName>wso2is-5.0.0.zip</destFileName>
                </artifactItem>                
              </artifactItems>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```